# LocalStorage not persisting data after we close the flutter app

Tags: flutter, local-storage

I am new to Flutter and developing app which needs to store some amount of data in LocalStorage, I am successfully storing and retrieving data to and from LocalStorage but when I close the App and reopens it, it flushes the entire data, and when we try to access the same data it gives Null. I am attaching my sample code here how I am doing it. Its working fine only issue is it does not persist data after restarting an APP.

```
void saveData() async{

    final LocalStorage storage = new LocalStorage('brick-game');

    await storage.setItem('data', _data);  

}


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

        final LocalStorage storage = new LocalStorage('brick-game');

        final data  = storage.getItem('data');

};
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong or anything I am missing. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

For some reason you have to await the local storage to be `ready` (This should be done automatically though). So, before calling `getItem()` you need `await storage.ready;`, like so:

```dart
Future<DataType> _getData() async {
  final LocalStorage storage = new LocalStorage('brick-game');
  await storage.ready;
  return await storage.getItem('data');
}
```

and then in your `build` method you can use a `FutureBuilder<T>()` to build your UI.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder<DataType>(
    future: _getData,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) // we read data from storage
      else if (snapshot.hasError) // an error occured
      else // we are still loading
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: this worked for me , it happened after upgrading flutter version and project packages.

Answer (score 1):

local storage has a `ready` method, that means it takes a while to can access storage

your save method is `async` and you set items with `await` keyword, but when you launch the app again you get items without `await` keyword

try to make a method for getting items

```
getItems() async {
   final LocalStorage storage = new LocalStorage('brick-game');

   final data  = await storage.getItem('data');
   print(data);
}



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){

     getItems().then((_){
        print(data);
     });

};
```

Comment: I tested this but still not persisting the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you created an abstraction for it you need initialize it in main function.
such as

> await AppGeneralCacheInitilization.instance.initializeCacheService();

by this way we are sure that the storage is available.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the storage to be ready, you can do that by using the `ready` getter from your LocalStorage instance.

```
// Note tha this has to be inside an async function
LocalStorage storage = LocalStorage('mykey');
await storage.ready;
// Do your storage manipulation here
```

If you don't want to await for the storage to be ready everytime you can add it to your App State in main.dart while initializing.

Turn your `void main()` into `void main() async` and put a `await storage.ready` there.